# Product featured image as a background in a query

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

```
<?php $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'product_cat' => 'summer',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    );
    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
    echo '<div class="wrap valshow" style="background: url(.echo $src[0];. ) !important;" role="banner">';
    echo '<figcaption><h3><a rel="' .get_permalink(). '" href="' .get_permalink(). ' ">';
        the_title();
    echo '</a></h3></figcaption>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I am trying to assemble a query for woocommerce which shows the title which this does. I need to add a button which will also link to the product.

The issue I am trying to figure out is how to get the products feature image set as a background where I have it in the code above. I found some code which works in a normal loop. I have tried to use

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```

where i have echo $src[0]; but all I get is an image above the div and not as a background. I feel like I'm close... Any help would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `echo` under `echo`

use this :

`echo '<div class="wrap valshow" style="background: url(' . $src[0]; . ') !important;" role="banner">';`

Also, if you are using `the_post_thumbnail('full');` , it outputs the whole image tag.